# Undo svn remove command

Tags: svn, version-control

I wanted to add a certain set of files in a directory using svn into repository. I did following to achieve this:

svn add graph_data/

This added whole directory whereas i needed only certain files. To remove this,

I did 'svn remove graph_data/' which showed following error:

svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: 'graph_data' has local modifications

I then used, 'svn remove --force graph_data/' which removed the folder from my local filesystem itself, shouldnt this be removing the folder from svn only, **Also how do i get back the folder ?**

P.S. 'svn revert' doesnt seem to work here as these files were only on my local filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will indeed delete the files from your working copy and mark them for removal from the repository on the next commit.

That's why it warned you that you have local modifications that would be lost, and asked you to add --force to the command line to be sure that you really really meant it...

Comment: Is there any way/tool to get my files back?

Comment: No, not unless you have some other backups (Mac's TimeMachine?)

Comment: @bilkulbekar depending on the filesystem of the drive those files have been stored you may be able to recover them. Just search for "file recovery [yourFileSystem]"

Answer (score 0):

svn add only schedule files for addition to the repository. They will be uploaded and added to the repository on your next commit. If you add something and change your mind before committing, you can unschedule the addition using svn revert. 
svn revert should work as it is intended to undo local changes.

Comment: Being new to svn, I used svn remove instead of svn revert, but is there any way to undo this now?

Comment: svn won't help you as the changes were done localy. Check the trash bin as a last chance. Finger crossed.